# Updating useContext after adding new value to an object in the array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, cart

I have a shopping cart that I want to update with new values depending on user choice from select/option.
When the user selects quantity my useEffect triggers and the new value is added to my object (to exact child element that is used).

```
function ProductData({ price, id }) {
  const [itemsInCart, setItemsInCart] = useContext(ItemsInCartContext);
  const quantity = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
  const [chosenQuantity, setChosenQuantity] = useState(1);

  const quantityHandler = (quantity) => {
    setChosenQuantity(quantity.target.value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const updateProductValue = () => {
      const item = itemsInCart.find((item) => item.listing_id === id);

      item.value = chosenQuantity * price;
    };
    updateProductValue();
    // How to update itemsInCart array of objects with new item value?
  }, [chosenQuantity]);

  return (
    <>
      <Quantity>
        Quantity:
        <Select value={chosenQuantity} onChange={(e) => quantityHandler(e)}>
          {quantity.map((number) => (
            <option key={Math.random()} value={number}>
              {number}
            </option>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </Quantity>
      <Price>${price}</Price>
    </>
  );
}
```

Now my edited object is not stored in local storage (useContext).
How can I update my ItemsInCartContext in useEffect so the new value stays in the cart?

Comment: can you clarify which object you're talking about?

Comment: "is not stored in local storage (useContext)", what does it means? Context API is not local storage

Comment: It is an empty array and potential object that can be added is an api object with many values inside and I set new one to be "value".

Comment: My state in created context is
``` const [itemsInCart, setItemsInCart] = useLocalStorage("item", []);```
That's why I mention local storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep state immutable, and also call `setItemsInCart` so set it,
the straight forward way is mapping the target item id:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setItemsInCart((prev) => {
    const newItems = prev.map((item) => {
      if (item.listing_id !== id) return item;
      return {
        ...item,
        value: chosenQuantity * price,
      };
    });

    return newItems;
  });
}, [chosenQuantity]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That works perfect now.  Would you mind explaining why I shouldn't mutate my array, but replace it with new one?

Comment: See https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#the-power-of-not-mutating-data